# JS ES6: Get parameters as an object with destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to get the function's arguments as an object (in order to iterate on it) using destructuring?

```
function({a=1, b=2, c=3}={}) {
  // how to get {a:1, b:2, c:3}?
}
```

My goal here is to bind each parameter to `this` in a class constructor.

It is possible without destructuring:

```
class Test {
  constructor(args) {
    Object.assign(this, args);
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to simplify that:

```
class Test {
  constructor({a=1, b=2, c=3}={}) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}

let test = new Test();
// test.a = 1 
// test.b = 2 etc.
```

Comment: So you want your callers to call the function with an object?

Comment: While I've posted an option for you below, can I just say, the `this.a = a;` form is nice and clear, easy to read, easy to debug...

Comment: I see. But when there is a lot of parameters it can be a bit inconvenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, using the shorthand form of object creation:

```
class Test {
  constructor({a=1, b=2, c=3}={}) {
    Object.assign(this, {a, b, c});
  }
}
```

Example:

```js
class Test {
  constructor({a=1, b=2, c=3}={}) {
    Object.assign(this, {a, b, c});
  }
}
const t1 = new Test();
console.log("t1:", t1.a, t1.b, t1.c);
const t2 = new Test({b: 42});
console.log("t2:", t2.a, t2.b, t2.c);
```

---

Alternately, don't use destructuring, and use multiple arguments to `Object.assign`:

```js
class Test {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, Test.defaults, options);
  }
}
Test.defaults = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

// Usage:
const t1 = new Test();
console.log("t1:", t1.a, t1.b, t1.c);
const t2 = new Test({b: 42});
console.log("t2:", t2.a, t2.b, t2.c);
```

...and if you want any of those as discrete things you can reference by name, you can either just use `this.a` (and `this.b` and `this.c`) to do it, or you can do:

```
let {a, b, c} = this;
```

...afterward and use those. (Just beware that *assigning* to the resulting `a`, `b`, and `c` won't update the object.)

Comment: Nice! There is no way to access the object with an equivalent of `arguments`?

Comment: @hhh: Not that handles the default values, no. The object passed in is indeed available as `arguments[0]`, but in its original form, and only if it's passed in.

Comment: Ok! Thank you that was the purpose of my question!

Comment: @hhh: I have just updated with an alternative for you that I think you might like better. Doesn't use destructuring, though.